# Is there a way to conditionally create/clone an element and assign it to a variable in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have created variable like this:

```
 const Component = useMemo(() => {
    if (selectable || multi) {
      return React.cloneElement('div', {
        className: classes.contentDetail,
      });
    }
    return React.cloneElement(RouterLink, {
      className: classes.contentDetail,
      to: { pathname: '/abcd/xyz' },
    });
  }, [selectable, multi]);
```

But when I use this component in JSX, it throws a react invalid element type error?

```
<Component>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</Component>
```

I can solve my problem using another approach, but I just want to know **if there is a way to conditionally assign a component to a variable while passing different props**.

Comment: Why not just define a component that takes `selectable, multi` as props and returns JSX conditionally?

Comment: Hey @RameshReddy, as I mentioned in my question. There can be numerous ways to solve this problem. But that's not the point of this question. The purpose of this question is to understand if I can conditionally assign the component with props to a variable or not.

Comment: You're trying to use JSX as a component. `<Component></Component>` is something you would use for actual components and `React.cloneElement('div')` doesn't return one.

Comment: I guess that's not totally correct as I can use this code `const Component = selectable ? 'div' : RouterLink`, and it will work fine. The problem is, I want to pass different props while assigning the component to the variable. `React.cloneElement(RouterLink)` doesn't work either. I am using this cloneElement because of the props.

Comment: `const Component = selectable ? 'div' : RouterLink` works because `RouterLink` is a component and in the case of `'div'`, React will use it as an HTML tag so it didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple issues here, first you are passing a string to clone which should be a proper html element or component `React.cloneElement(<div></div>, ...)` for example.

Secondly the syntax is as follows:

```
React.cloneElement(element, [props], [...children])
```

So you can pass children when cloning, which will already return a component rendered with the props/children you passed in, So to use that in the render function of your component (after passing children):

```
 return Component
```

[Link to docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments just use `{Component}` instead of `<Component></Component>` because of what gets returned from `React.cloneElement`.

Also, use `<div />` instead of "div" as DannyMoshe says.

```
export default function App() {
  const Component = useMemo(() => {
    return React.cloneElement(<div />, {
      className: "contentDetail",
      children: <p>Hello World!</p>
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {Component}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit eloquent-zeh-8c6x4]